# How to use a private GitLab branch as a dependency in package.json?

Tags: npm

I am trying to use a specific branch from a private GitLab repository in one of my projects for testing purposes. I have structured my git URL in my package.json like this:

```
"dependencies": {
"@dependency": "git+https://oauth2:<my_access_token>@gitlab.com/<path_to_repository>#<specific_branch_name>"}
```

I then removed node_modules and did a clean install. Everything installs correctly, however I do not see the changes I made from the specific branch. Instead, it appears to be pulling only from master.

How can I pull my changes from a specific branch?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, though with:
`"my-lib": "git+ssh://git@<gitlab-url>:<project>.git#<branch-name>",`

I'm sure I've done this in the past. Wondering if some hidden error is causing a re-direct to master. Not very transparent though

Comment: it is working for me. There was a hidden error on a post-install script.

I managed to see the error by installing all other dependencies with `npm ci`, while this was commented out, then run `npm i` after uncommenting. This only installed my dep, and did it on a more verbose way.
Hugely frustrating.